# Does *(NULL) compile successfully by the C99 standard?

Tags: c, c99

I understand this code should never be executed but does `*(NULL)` compile successfully by the C99  standard ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    *(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

PS: Running it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/re2qrk) returns 0 but I do not know the compiler version being used :(

Comment: “Running it on ideone seems to work”: Define “work”. Do you mean that it crashes as expected or that it returns the error code `0`?

Comment: Yes. C99 will allow you to compile that.

Comment: C99 does not "allow" it.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Are you asking if the code should compile, or if its behavior is well defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*(NULL)` is always a constraint violation. `*(NULL)` as a full expression is "not compilable" in C under any definition of `NULL`. `NULL` can be defined an integral zero, which is obviously not dereferencible. `NULL` can be defined as integral zero cast to `void *` type, but dereferencing `void *` pointers is illegal in C.

**Note:** I'm still not entirely sure whether my statement above about dereferencing `void *` pointer is correct. Is it a constraint violation or not? The standard does not spell it out explicitly. But at the same time it defines the behavior of unary `*` for pointers to functions and pointers to objects only. Meanwhile, `void` is not an object type.

If it is indeed legal to dereference `void *` pointers, then `*(NULL)` by itself would produce undefined behavior (assuming `(void *) 0` definition of `NULL`). But there is still one context in which `*(NULL)` might be valid *as a subexpression*. It is `&*(NULL)`. The language gives special treatment to `&*` combination, making it a no-op with well-defined behavior even in situations where `*` alone would produce undefined behavior.

Comment: +1 for the *only* correct answer (so far). My only quibble is that the C standard doesn't use the term "illegal". Even with a constraint violation or syntax error, a compiler may issue a warning (which qualifies as a "diagnostic") and continue to compile it.

Comment: My apologies, I spoke too soon. It would certainly make sense for defeferencing a `void*` to be a constraint violation, and I assumed it was. But the only relevant constraint in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.5.3.2 is "The operand of the unary * operator shall have pointer type." Which makes me wonder about `int n; void *ptr = &n; &ptr;`. `&ptr` would then be an expression of type `void`, which is permitted. It's odd for the standard to leave the behavior undefined when it's so easy to detect at compile time.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: That's what I thought to. (BTW, I presume you meant `*ptr` in your comment). Note that `*ptr` is not just an expression of type `void`, it is actually an *lvalue* of type `void`. The only use I see for such an lvalue is to immediately become an operand of unary `&`. Maybe that is the reason it was allowed.

Comment: To be strict, any call of a `void` function would be such a constraint violation if `*void_pointer` was one. Besides of any side effects, I don't see a difference between `void_returning_function();` and `*void_pointer;`. So the only uncertainty can stem from dereferencing `NULL`, which indeed might be problematic.

Comment: @glglgl: Firstly, the difference between `void_returning_function()` and `*void_pointer` is considerable: the former is not an lvalue, the latter is. I.e. it the the difference between value context and object context. What object does `*void_pointer` refer to? Secondly, while it might seem logical to allow `*void_pointer` just because we can have void functions, the language does not always follow that logic. For example, in C it is illegal to do `void foo() { return foo(); }`, i.e. it is illegal to literally return `void` "values" from void functions. (It is legal in C++, BTW).

Comment: While dereferencing NULL is an undefined behavior, I don't think the compiler should reject `*(NULL);` simply on account of its return type being void, for she same reasons glglgl said. However, trying to *use* or affect the value (e.g. `int a= *(NULL)`), or even using the sizeof operator, should be rejected because void has no size and can't be converted.

Answer (score 5):

If `NULL` is defined as simply `0` (which is permitted), then `*(0)` is a constraint violation and must be diagnosed. If `NULL` is defined as `((void *)0)` then `*((void *)0)` invokes undefined behavior (by dereferencing a null pointer) and the compiler is not required to issue any diagnostic, but the program is also not required to behave the way you expect it to.

Comment: I was under impression that dereferencing `void *` pointers is always illegal in C, regardless of whether the pointer value is valid or not. Which means that the code contains constraint violation even for `(void *) 0` definition of `NULL`. The standard does not spell it explicitly though...

Comment: So the question of whether it's a constraint violation or undefined behavior is implementation-defined.

Comment: You might want to mention that dereferencing a `void*` pointer is not by itself a constraint violation (though I don't know why it isn't).

Comment: The only case I can think of where one might legitimately dereference a `void*` is something like `&(*((void*)ptr))` (presumably as the product of a sequence of macro expansions).

Comment: @pburka: That does not count as a dereference. See C99 6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators, para 3: "If the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the result is not an lvalue."

Comment: @R..: The term "dereference" only appears once in the spec, in a footnote. Assuming that dereference is a synonym for indirect, then there is an dereference, because the `*` unary operator is the indirection operator. In this case, the indirection constraints are enforced, but the indirection is not evaluated. It's only in this special case of non-evaluation that it makes sense to indirect a `void*`.

Comment: To clarify, I was not using the word "dereference" formally, just in the sense of "it's UB to dereference a null or otherwise invalid pointer".

Comment: Just b the way: NULL isn't simply defined as `0` mostly it is defined as `(void *) 0` ;)

Answer (score 0):

`*(NULL)` is undefined behavior.

From the horse mouth:

> (C99, 6.5.3.2.p4) "If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is undefined.87)"

And (emphasis mine):

> 87): "**Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the    unary * operator are a null pointer**, an address inappropriately aligned for the type of object pointed to, and the address of an object after the end of its lifetime."

And of course, `NULL` is a null pointer:

> (C99, 7.17p3) "The macros [..] NULL which expands to an implementation-defined null    pointer constant;"

As with all programs that invoke undefined behavior, a compiler has the right to not compile it (see C99, 3.4.3p2).